# Integral question regarding area?

Tags: integration

I have to Find the integral ∫∫ L (xy-x^2)dx - (x+y)^2 dy where L is the triangle with the verticles O (0;0) A (3,1) and B (2,2)..so I thought about

taking ∫∫ L (xy-x^2)dx - (x+y)^2 dy and separating it in three different parts,and calculate each,OA AB BA and take the sum,but if we find the double integral for example for OA,how do we put the values in the definite integral?

Edit: I have to solve this without Green...

Answer (score 1):

First invoke Green's theorem, which states that

$$\oint_L (P dx+Q dy) = \iint_T dx dy \left (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right )$$

where $T$ is the interior of the triangle.  Here

$$Q(x,y) = -(x+y)^2$$
$$P(x,y) = x y-x^2$$

So the double integral becomes

$$-\iint_T dx dy\, (3 x+2 y)$$

To evaluate this, you will need to break the integral up into two pieces: one of which is bounded by the lines $OB$ and $OA$, the other bounded by the lines $AB$ and $OA$. This will end up looking like

$$-\int_0^2 dx \, \int_{x/3}^x dy (3 x+2 y) - \int_2^3 dx \, \int_{x/3}^{4-x} dy (3 x+2 y)$$

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: Oh ron thanks,but can this be solved without Green?

Comment: @mathobs: well, as you mentioned, by evaluating the three line integrals about the triangle.